# "Legended" not working with "Plot" or "LogLinearPlot"

Tags: plotting, legending

Version 9 has a new option `Legended`, which I find appealing since it should allow me to add individual expressions/curves to a legend, but it doesn't seem to be working for expressions in `Plot` or `LogLinearPlot`.

For example, I would like to plot $log(x)$ and $x sin(x)$ together but only have $log(x)$ appear in the legend, I try:

```
LogLinearPlot[{Legended[Log[x], "Log(x)"], x Sin[x]}, {x, 1, 100}]
```

and the curve for $Log(x)$ just disappears instead of appearing on it's own in the legend. If `Legended` is not supposed to be used with the "`Plot`..." family of symbols, then could someone suggest an alternative solution to my problem?

Comment: Yes, that does work for this particular example, because the Log[x] appears first. The complete set of expressions I'm using is a larger than this one and I think the ordering is important since I'm using filling between the curves, which needs to get layered in a particular order (I'll check to see if there's a way I can put all of the legended expressions first). What if I need to put expressions that appear later in the list into the Legend but omit earlier ones? Perhaps I should try to edit my question to include the fact that ordering is important?

Comment: The documentation for `Legended` states that *Legended can be used as a symbolic wrapper for **data elements and datasets** in functions such as ListPlot and BarChart.* So it does appear that it is not intended to work with the `Plot*` family.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks Simon.

Comment: @SimonWoods Do you know why `LogLinearPlot[{Log[x], x Sin[x], x Cos[x]}, {x, 1, 100}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Log(x)", None, "x Cos(x)"}]` does not work then ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks, looks like a bug to me. `PlotLegends -> LineLegend@{"Log(x)", None, "x Cos(x)"}` works though.

Comment: @SimonWoods A bug for me too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do :

```
LogLinearPlot[{Log[x], x Sin[x], x Cos[x]}, {x, 1, 100}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Log(x)", None, "x Cos(x)"}, After]]
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers, that works nicely!